# addition breaks "if" statement in fragment shader

Tags: glsl, webgl, precision, floating-accuracy, fragment-shader

I am experiencing a weird behavior in my fragment shaders.

If I test 3 values separately, my "if" statement passes as expected and draws the green square properly:

```
if(column == 324. && row == 616.*896. && slice == 31.*896.*896.){
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0., 1., 0., 1.);
}
```

[image]

If I add the values and test the sum, the "if" statement doesn't pass as expected anymore. It also draws in green the squares where columns = 323 and 325.

```
if(column + row + slice == 25439556.){
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0., 1., 0., 1.);
}
```

[image]

I understand it might be some kind of precision issues but I could not get the sum to pass properly the "if" statement.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Best,
Nicolas

== MORE ABOUT WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE ==

I store lot of data in textures then I want to access this data. I access this data through an index (rows+columns+slice). Problem is that even if rows, columns and slice appear correct, the sum rows+columns+slice is incorrect.

Therefore, my index to access the data is not correct.

In the following example

```
if(column + row + slice == 25439556.){
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0., 1., (326. - column) / 3., 1.);
}
```

[image]

, column 323, 324 and 325 refer to the same index (column + row + slice), even though columns are different and row and slice constants. You can see with the different value of the "B" channel that columns are different.

The different if conditions work as stated:

```
// WORKS
if(column == 324. && row + slice == 616.*896. + 31.*896.*896.)
if(column + row == 324. + 616.*896. && slice == 31.*896.*896.)

// DOESN't WORK
if(column + slice == 324. + 31.*896.*896. && row == 616.*896.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a fundamental flaw for what you're trying to do, which is try to compare floating point values directly. The dot that you add to the end of the digit makes it a float (see [GLSL specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf), p. 32), and what happens is exactly what you would expect: sometimes the comparison passes, sometimes it fails, depending on what numbers you add and multiply together.

GLSL spec pp. 39-40 states:

> When performing implicit conversion for binary operators, there may be multiple data types to which the
>   two operands can be converted. For example, when adding an int value to a uint value, both values can
>   be implicitly converted to uint, float, and double. In such cases, **a floating-point type is chosen if either
>   operand has a floating-point type**.

It seems to me this is what happens. Your integer column and row values are implicitly converted to floats, which do not precisely match the results of the floating point arithmetic operations.

If you want to do it properly, why not use integer literals? Clearly you are working with integer data since the variables are column and row indices.

Comment: Yes reducing type conversions to the minimum required fixed everything.